# How can I Check if a TextInput has a Text to Search in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

im trying to search into a IconsGroup in my application some elements with a "code", using a TextInput and validating if contains the code of any icons in the group.

```
if(iconsGroup.numElements > 0) {
  for(var i:int = 0; i<iconsGroup.numElements; i++) {
     if(iconsGroup.getElementAt(i) is R_VO) { 
        if((iconsGroup.getElementAt(i) as R_VO)._extintores != null 
           && (txtBuscar.text.indexOf((iconsGroup.getElementAt(i) as R_VO)._extintores._codigo)) > -1) {
    shake_AfterSearch(i);
        }
     }
}
```

But my problem right now is if I search a text:

> "Code_1"

and

> "CODE_1"

Exists a way to search it and find both Icons with the code "Code_1" or "CODE_1"?, I want to search it without case sensitive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use `toLowerCase()` on strings. In your case it will be looked next:

```
var buscarText:String = txtBuscar.text.toLowerCase();
var searchedText:String;

if(iconsGroup.numElements > 0) {
  for(var i:int = 0; i<iconsGroup.numElements; i++) {
     searchedText = (iconsGroup.getElementAt(i) as R_VO)._extintores._codigo.toLowerCase();
     if(iconsGroup.getElementAt(i) is R_VO) { 
        if((iconsGroup.getElementAt(i) as R_VO)._extintores != null 
           && (buscarText.indexOf(searchedText)) > -1) {
            shake_AfterSearch(i);
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but what happend if I save the code like "CoDe_1"?

Comment: When you use "toLowerCase()" all chars will be lowered in that string. CoDe_1, CODE_1, code_1, cODE_1 and similar will turn to code_1.